# an error "target is not defined", and the code still work

Tags: javascript, events

I have the following Code, also you can find here([Online test](http://jsfiddle.net/lionking0/98KCy)).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dvBox"> Div box </div>
<span id="SpBox"> Span box </span>
<p id="pBox"> P box </p>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    target.style.backgroundColor = (target.style.backgroundColor == "")?"green" : "";
};

target.onmouseover = function(){
    target.style.cursor = "pointer";
};
```

Although there is an error: `target is not defined` in the part `target.onmouseover = function(){`, but the code is still work.

But I want to know how code is work and in this part `var target = e.target;`, I have declared about the variable `target` as a local variable, because it is within anonymous function `document.body.onclick = function(e)`, and after that, I have used it in outside the anonymous function in a global scope, here `target.onmouseover = function(){`

**Note:** the code does not works fine in jsfiddle link ([Online test](http://jsfiddle.net/lionking0/98KCy)), but in the browsers works fine, but with an error.

Can you please explain to me, How this code works fine, and in same time give me an error?

Comment: The `target.onmouseover` code isn't doing anything. The fiddle works the same if you comment it out: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/98KCy/3/

Comment: @Barmar: Please see my note that in the bottom of my question.

Comment: Unless you can post a link to where it's supposedly "working", I don't see how we can answer you. All we can see is what the fiddle does.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code `target.onmouseover = function(){target.style.cursor = "pointer";};` works only in the browsers, but does not work on fiddle. You can copy the code to your editor if you want to see.

Comment: when do you want to view the pointer? 1.on every element everytime,2.only after clicked on the clicked element,3.on green elements

Comment: @cocco: When the mouse be on the element before and after click, but When move the mouse away from the element the cursor come back again to default,

Comment: then both my solutions should work...the point is you need to define some check to do not display the cursor everythime as everything is a e.target inside your body clickhandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
body>*:hover{
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

this sets every element inside body to be a cursor onmouseover

replace `*` with the elements,classes,ids which you want to apply the class;

http://jsfiddle.net/98KCy/4/

**Solution 2**

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
    if(e.target.parentNode.nodeName=='BODY'){
     e.target.style.cursor='pointer'
    }
},false);
```

replace `e.target.parentNode.nodeName=='BODY'` with a check of the clickable elements

http://jsfiddle.net/98KCy/5/

the point is you need to define somehow the elements you want use as clickable.

i personallt use div's as clickable elements inside certain containers which has an id. i just add the `#id>div:hover{/*style*/}` or if i need to use js i add this simple check inside the handle function event: `e.target.parendNode.id==id`

Answer (score 1):

The code before the error works. That is normal.  The erroneous code and any code that is after the error will not work.

Answer (score 0):

the code works because unlike you said, the error given comes from your second function and not the first.
your handler function is depending on an unassigned variable named target. To prove this you can comment your second function and for instance insert a console.log('hello world') right at the end of your first function and you will see that not only you won't have an error but the hello world will run every time you trigger the event clicking anywhere in the page

Comment: Yes, you are correct. do you have a solution to this problem ?

Comment: yes, get rid of second function and use css to give the cursor property you want. body{cursor: pointer} but if you really really want to do it in javascript do this: document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer'; there is no point on having an eventhandler for mouseovers that triggers everytime time you mouseover any element in the page, when you can just change the page body css property that does it